# Create new dataframe - substract one column for the other

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a Shiny application where user can choose columns to subtract one from another and write a name of the column. I got stuck with printing the dataframe, probably because Shiny does not want to  consider column the way I would like to. Does any one know how to select column by input variable?

Generally, I would like to include in df only Samples that user specify, like in the print screen provided (Sample3/4 which are NULL should be ignored). Does anyone has any suggestions how to deal with the problem?

Here is a part of my code:

```
    library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 3,
          div(style = "white-space: nowrap;", 
              div(style = "white-space: nowrap;", 

                  h5(textInput("name1", label = "Sample 1 Name", value = "Enter name..."),style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "sam1", label = "Sample 1",c(),  multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "bla1", label = "Blank 1",c(), multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;")
              ),
              div(style = "white-space: nowrap;",

                  h5(textInput("name2", label = "Sample 2 Name", value = "Enter name..."),style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "sam2", label = "Sample 2",c(),  multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "bla2", label = "Blank 2",c(), multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;")
              ),
              div(style = "white-space: nowrap;",

                  h5(textInput("name3", label = "Sample 3 Name", value = "Enter name..."),style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "sam3", label = "Sample 3",c(),  multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "bla3", label = "Blank 3",c(), multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;")
              ),
              div(style = "white-space: nowrap;",


                  h5(textInput("name4", label = "Sample 4 Name", value = "Enter name..."),style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "sam4", label = "Sample 4",c(),  multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "bla4", label = "Blank 4",c(), multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;")
              ),
              actionButton("update", "Update", class = "btn-primary",style='padding:4px; font-size:120%')
          )))),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("contents"),
      plotOutput("plot_preview", height = "auto")
    )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Layout <- c("A", " B", " A", "B")

  col1 <- c(0.84, 0.65, 0.97, 0.81)
  col2 <- c(0.43,0.55,0.53,0.66)
  col3 <- c(0.74, 0.75, 0.87, 0.71)

  df <- data.frame(Layout, col1, col2, col3) 

  cols <- colnames(df) 
  cols <- c("NULL", cols[2:4])

  updateSelectInput(session, "sam1", choices=cols)
  updateSelectInput(session, "sam2", choices=cols)
  updateSelectInput(session, "sam3", choices=cols)
  updateSelectInput(session, "sam4", choices=cols)
  updateSelectInput(session, "bla1", choices=cols)
  updateSelectInput(session, "bla2", choices=cols)
  updateSelectInput(session, "bla3", choices=cols)
  updateSelectInput(session, "bla4", choices=cols)

 ## take a colum choosed before and substract the blank - save as one column 
 observeEvent(input$update, 
              {mydatanew <- reactive(
                mydatanew <- data.frame(input$name1 = input$sam1 - input$bla1, input$name2 = input$sam2 - input$bla2))

              output$contents2 <- DT::renderDataTable( DT::datatable(mydatanew()))
             }
              )


  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable(df)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And a sample user input:
[image: sample user input]

Comment: You can't use `$` with variable column names, but you can use `[[`. Suggested duplicate of the [Dynamically select data frame columns R-FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222286/903061). (At least partially a dupe - good background reading regardless.)

Comment: Also, I'm not really sure what you're going for in the `mydatanew <-` line, do you mean to be doing comparisons with `==`? Or do you want argument assignment with `=`?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a separate `contents2` output? Or are you trying to replace the original table? I'm not sure what the desired behavior is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `reactiveVal` to hold your dataframe and update it. Use the `observeEvent` to add columns and store the modified dataframe back into the reactiveVal.

Also, to make things a little easier, you can call an input as `input[[x]]`, where x is a string. So we can loop over the inputs instead of typing everything out. You could probably also use that for your updateSelectInput statements. It would also maybe be nice to reset the `selectInput` elements after you press the `actionButton`. You can do that by placing lines like `lapply(1:4,function(x) {updateSelectInput(session,paste0('bla',x),selected='NULL')})`
 at the end of your `observeEvent`.

Below is a working example. Hope this helps!

---

[image]

---

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 3,
          div(style = "white-space: nowrap;", 
              div(style = "white-space: nowrap;", 

                  h5(textInput("name1", label = "Sample 1 Name", value = "Enter name..."),style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "sam1", label = "Sample 1",c(),  multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "bla1", label = "Blank 1",c(), multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;")
              ),
              div(style = "white-space: nowrap;",

                  h5(textInput("name2", label = "Sample 2 Name", value = "Enter name..."),style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "sam2", label = "Sample 2",c(),  multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "bla2", label = "Blank 2",c(), multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;")
              ),
              div(style = "white-space: nowrap;",

                  h5(textInput("name3", label = "Sample 3 Name", value = "Enter name..."),style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "sam3", label = "Sample 3",c(),  multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "bla3", label = "Blank 3",c(), multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;")
              ),
              div(style = "white-space: nowrap;",


                  h5(textInput("name4", label = "Sample 4 Name", value = "Enter name..."),style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "sam4", label = "Sample 4",c(),  multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;"),
                  h5(selectInput(inputId = "bla4", label = "Blank 4",c(), multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;")
              ),
              actionButton("update", "Update", class = "btn-primary",style='padding:4px; font-size:120%')
          )))),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("contents"),
      plotOutput("plot_preview", height = "auto")
    )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Layout <- c("A", " B", " A", "B")

  col1 <- c(0.84, 0.65, 0.97, 0.81)
  col2 <- c(0.43,0.55,0.53,0.66)
  col3 <- c(0.74, 0.75, 0.87, 0.71)

  df <- data.frame(Layout, col1, col2, col3) 

  cols <- colnames(df) 
  cols <- c("NULL", cols[2:4])

  updateSelectInput(session, "sam1", choices=cols)
  updateSelectInput(session, "sam2", choices=cols)
  updateSelectInput(session, "sam3", choices=cols)
  updateSelectInput(session, "sam4", choices=cols)
  updateSelectInput(session, "bla1", choices=cols)
  updateSelectInput(session, "bla2", choices=cols)
  updateSelectInput(session, "bla3", choices=cols)
  updateSelectInput(session, "bla4", choices=cols)

  reval_df <- reactiveVal(df)

  ## take a colum choosed before and substract the blank - save as one column 
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    df <- reval_df()
    for (i in 1:4)
    {
      if(input[[paste0('sam',i)]]!='NULL' & input[[paste0('bla',i)]]!='NULL')
      {
        print(i)
        df[[input[[paste0('name',i)]]]] = df[[input[[paste0('sam',i)]]]]- df[[input[[paste0('bla',i)]]]]
      }
    }
    reval_df(df)

    # reset inputs
    lapply(1:4,function(x) {updateSelectInput(session,paste0('bla',x),selected='NULL')})
    lapply(1:4,function(x) {updateSelectInput(session,paste0('name',x),selected='NULL')})
    lapply(1:4,function(x) {updateSelectInput(session,paste0('sam',x),selected='NULL')})


  })


  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable(reval_df())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```